# Malcolm McLaren "Soweto" lyrics

Tags: lyrics

[Malcolm McLaren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_McLaren) - *Soweto* lyrics from the album [Duck Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Rock).

I have looked everywhere to find these song lyrics and they just don't seem to exist! Anybody have any leads?

Comment: I seem to recall that the album had lyrics on the inner sleeve. I can't find my copy at the moment but will look again when putting away Christmas decorations in January and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 2):

*On the [Discogs page](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Malcolm-McLaren-Duck-Rock/master/68613) I could find a scan of the inner sleeve. It was small and hard to read and I had to check with the music. I removed he repeated lyrics when they are repeated several times (replacing it by [ . . . ]). Finally, I removed all the "yeah, yes, believe me, ...".*

*Here there are:*

```
All you Gotta do is Start
Forget about pushing you Cart
I will make you Step Out

All the men shall Boogie and Bark
Never be afraid of the Dark
[ . . . ]

All Xhosa Zulu Sangoma, Witchdoctor
Say Shangaans the Boogie Beater
[ . . . ]

All the men do the Boogie, Don't Fear
Living in the Road in Soweto
[ . . . ]

All you Gotta do is Break and Fall
Head over heels, move Backwards
Get down, on your hands and knees Go Forward
Clap! Clap! Clap! Clap! Clap!
Move your legs from side to side
Like an Animal with nowhere to hide
Roll over, with your back on the ground
Let your seat bump, up and down
Stand up, with your knees bent and hands down
Gallop like a horse accros the ground
Hands on your hips, up and down, up and down
And with your legs lift up and down
And then go twisting round and round
Shtwela! Shtwela!

All Xhosa Zulu Sangoma, Witchdoctor
Say Shangaans the Boogie Beater
[ . . . ]

All you Gotta do is Start

All the men do the Boogie, Don't Fear
Living in the Road in Soweto

All dressed up magic in my head, in my Head
Sounds that make you dance til you're Dead
All dressed up magic in my head, in my Head
Living in the Road in Soweto
```